# Change color of ion-datetime value

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, colors

How is it possible to change ion-datetime value color?
Documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#css-custom-properties show only css variable for the placeholder color.

But how the value color can be changed?

**--color:** has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

When no CSS variable is defined on the Ionic element, you can simply use normal CSS declarations:

```
ion-datetime {
    color: #f90;
}
```

This could be done in a single component's CSS file or globally to target all `ion-datetime` across the entire applicaiton.

**Update**

To target the placeholder without affecting values:

```
ion-datetime {
  --placeholder-color: #0f9;
}

&:not(.datetime-placeholder) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: this change also the placeholder colors, but I need to change only the value color, when the input is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved it like so on ***Ionic 5+/Angular***:

*global.scss*

```
ion-picker>.picker-wrapper {
    background-color: var(--dark-theme-color) !important;
}

.picker-opt {
    color: #7994A2 !important;
}

.picker-opt.picker-opt-selected {
    color: var(--ion-color-light) !important;
}

ion-datetime {
    color: var(--ion-color-light) !important;
}
```

[image]